# jqGrid colModel DateTime sort

Tags: jqgrid

How can i get the the JqGrid column to sort as per date time, here is what i tried.

```
{ "name": "PACT_DATE", "index": "PACT_DATE", "width": 55, "jsonmap":"PACT_DATE", "sorttype": "date", "datefmt": "Y-m-d H:i:s" }
```

I am still not getting my columns data to sort the AM/PM right

The Data i am getting from my backend webservice is in string format and I need to format it as DateTime so i could sort properly.

PACT_DATE = "3/21/2007 4:42:15 PM";

please help!

Comment: Could you post an example of data in which you post the date/time inside your JSON data? In the title of the question you used `DateTime`. In JavaScript there are no `DateTime` type or a standard class. Do you serialize `DateTime` from .NET or what do you mean? It is also not clear where you should have AM/PM in the data. Do you has AM/PM in JSON input? Do you want that jqGrid display the time in using AM/PM? Please write more exactly what do you mean.

Comment: the data i am getting back is in string format and hence it is sorted as text/string. The Data looks like following "3/21/2007 4:42:15 PM" and i tried updating ColModal to add formatter: 'date' but still its is sorted as text.  I shall edit my question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that AM/PM is part of the timestamp, using `A`. For example:

```
datefmt: "Y-m-d h:i:s A"
```